# Degrees of freedom in Gaussian Normal Coordinates in GR

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, degrees-of-freedom

I'm learning about GR and have been wondering about something. At any point, we can define Gaussian Normal Coordinates which are orthonormal and approximately flat (first derivative along all axes is 0).

In two dimensions, this can be thought of as a tangent plane to the point which lies on a curved manifold. Thus, in 2D, there is a rotational $U(1)$ degree of freedom (DOF) since we can rotate the tangent plane around in a circle.

In 3+1 dimensions, presumably there are more than one degree of freedom, but it's not quite clear to me how many there would be.

My question is, how do these degrees of freedom come into play in the theory of GR. Perhaps it would be easier to understand with the single DOF in 2D, and then elaborate on the number of DOFs in 3+1 dimensions and how these come into play.

Comment: The equivalent of rotations in 3+1 spacetime are the Lorentz transformations.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M$ be a $n$-dimensional maniflod and $g$ a Lorentzian metric on that.

Given $p\in M$, a **normal coordinate system centered at $p$** is a map (*)
$$V_0 \ni (x^1,\ldots,x^n) \mapsto \exp_{p}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x^k {\bf e}_k\right) \in M \tag{1}\:.$$
Above, $V_0\subset T_pM$ is a given, sufficiently small, starshaped open neighborhood of the zero vector  ${\bf 0} \in T_pM$ and $\{{\bf e}_k\}_{k=1,\ldots,n}$ is a given basis of $T_pM$.

In these coordinates
$$\frac{\partial g_{ab}}{\partial x^c}|_p =0$$
so that also the connection coeffients $\Gamma^{a}_{bc}$ vanish exactly at $p\equiv {\bf 0}$.

Here you can change two things obtaining a different  normal coordinate system always centered at $p$

- the shape of $V_0$;
- the basis $\{{\bf e}_k\}_{k=1,\ldots,n}$.

Assuming that $V_0$ is fixed, you can change the basis. As a consequence the **degrees of freedom** are the elements of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. That is the group of *all possible transformations of bases in $T_pM$*.

If you decide that the only admitted bases are *pseudo-orthonormal*, then the degrees of freedom boil down to the elements of $O(1,n-1)$.

In GR these degrees of freedom do not play a crucial role, as they are the same as in SR. However, in some [attempts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory_gravity) to describe the GR as a *gauge theory* (similarly to what done for the electromagnetic theory)  these groups play some role as they are (at least part of the) gauge group of the theory.

---

(*) The **exponential map** is defined as

$$\exp_p({\bf v}):= \gamma(p,{\bf v}, 1)$$

where $I_{p,{\bf v}} \ni t \mapsto \gamma(p,{\bf v}, t)$ is the unique maximal geodesic with initial data $\gamma(0)=p$, $\dot{\gamma}(0)={\bf v}$. $0\in I_{p,{\bf v}}\subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open interval, the maximal one for those intial conditions.

The restrictions on the choice of $V_p$ are due to the fact that one wants that (i) $1\in I_{p,{\bf v}}$ and that (ii) the map in (1) is a diffeomorphism onto its image.